# What treatment is necessary after welding carbon steel pipes?

Tags: welding

When welding stainless steel pipes, the welds need some treatment (e.g. ball blasting and pickling). Is there anything equivalent for carbon steel (not stainless)? I'm looking at a tender document where someone specified pickling etc. for C-steel and I'm wondering wether someone copy-pasted from the specifications for stainless steels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than inspection/NDE , the only treatment would be for appearance. For stick , you need to knock off the slag to examine it for quality. In some situations the hardness would be a concern and minor grinding for hardness tests would be needed. Stainless is the same; clean for inspection/NDE, anything else like glas bead blasting and pickling is for cosmetics. Let me add, if you have a non-engineer manager who just paid millions $ for a piece of stainless equipment , you don't want to see it arrive with gold,blue and black surfaces along the welds. So most vendors will clean-up the welds to avoid some unhappy customer phone calls.

Answer (score 2):

agree with blacksmith37. Here are the materials science issues.

the welding properties of low carbon steel from the standpoint of its time-temperature-transformation curves are well-enough understood by now that the quality of a weld in it can be determined by visual inspection and by swatting it with a 5-pound hammer. if it has the wrong color or flies apart, it's no good, and you go have a chat with the welder or the supplier of the steel.